# What is the new Azure ML Studio evaluate model visualization equivalent from ML Studio Classic?

Tags: azure, azure-machine-learning-service

There are many courses for ML Studio Classic, which is outdated, so I am stuck trying to navigate the new ML studio interface. For a Boosted Decision Tree evaluation model, after the job is done running, I can preview the data, but it looks nothing like what people are saying it can look like. I see std error and similar but not AUC, Precision... etc.

This is what everyone seems to look at:
[image]

but all I see is this:
[image]
2nd image refuses to work, basically just showing std error data table, not the visual.

I check multiple tabs, visuals, charting, output logs, can't seem to find any equivalent. I must be missing something?

Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

I have reproduced the scenario in Azure ML Pipeline and executed the training job.
To view the metrics from trained model, you can go to job overview:
[image]

You can find the evaluation metrics for a Boosted Decision Tree model by going to the **Metrics** tab.
The **Metrics** tab will show you a table of all of the evaluation metrics for the model, including AUC, Precision, and Recall.
[image]
[image]
Please refer to this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-visualize-jobs?view=azureml-api-2) for more details on visualize training job.

Note: Please check if your pipeline is properly configured with [Evaluate Model Component](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/component-reference/evaluate-model?view=azureml-api-2).